# Implementing threading concept in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multithreading, backbone.js

Is there any way to implement threading concept in javascript in its simplest form.
The situation is, in my app, if user tries to click one thing, the task can take a lot of time, so I want to allow user to do other things, if the task gets completed, he can get the results.
So if anyone has any idea about it please answer.

Thanks in advance.

Edited

The exact situation is User clicks to start a processs, the process needs to be executed at the server side and can take some time. So I will be pinging server every 5 or 10 seconds to check if this is done or not. Mean while user can do anything he wants.

Comment: Use a webworker if the task is done in javascript.

Comment: Look up `WebWorkers` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers

Comment: Note that the nature of the task might lead to a different answer.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Could you describe this situation a bit more? Your particular situation will affect what is most appropriate to do -- it may not require threading.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I have edited the question for a better clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Use Web workers:

> A web worker is a JavaScript that runs in the background,
>   independently of other scripts, without affecting the performance of
>   the page. You can continue to do whatever you want: clicking,
>   selecting things, etc., while the web worker runs in the background.

From http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp

You can see an example here:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_webworker

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is not multithreaded, although there are situations similar to that using `asyc`s or `setTimout` or `setInterval`, but these are features in JavaScript which don't have anything to do with multithreaded application.

But the [Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers) concept in `HTML5` allows you to do some jobs in background.

Be careful this feature currently is not supported in all browsers.